# Use a func and variable in swift

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hi this is my first post and even my first coding at all. 
i have a little problem with variables or functions.
under my button i have a variable RandomNumberGen it generate a random number and passed into a label for testing. it worked very fine. After that i want to use this generated number in a firebase query. her is the problem i can't call this randomnumbergen in that query.the purpose of the query is i will get a random data from firebase and but them into a label. but first i want get only 1 random data. 
 if i but

```
let RandomNumberGen = arc4random_uniform(209)
```

this line above the override function it works but this time i can't refresh and get other numbers. how can i solve this. 
Sorry for my bad language and poorly coding. But as a mentioned i am very new at coding and i jumped in to the see directly for learning :(.
Thanks for your help

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = DataService.ds.REF_QUOTES
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "quotesID").queryEqual(toValue: RandomNumberGen).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
            print(DataSnapshot)
        })

    }


    @IBAction func refreshBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        let RandomNumberGen = arc4random_uniform(209)
        txtLbl.text = String(describing: RandomNumberGen)
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you want to show `ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "quotesID").queryEqual(toValue: RandomNumberGen).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
            print(DataSnapshot)
        })` this function's **random** number value inside **txtLbl** ?

Comment: Nope, i want push the button and when i push the button i want generate a random number with that generated number i want use it in the dataservice where 'tovalue:RandomNumberGen' is.